# Side effects not realized without deref

Tags: concurrency, clojure

From clojure for the brave and true:

```
(defmacro enqueue
  [q concurrent-promise-name & work]
  (let [concurrent (butlast work)
        serialized (last work)]
    `(let [~concurrent-promise-name (promise)]
       (future (deliver ~concurrent-promise-name (do ~@concurrent)))
       (deref ~q)
       ~serialized
       ~concurrent-promise-name)))
(defmacro wait
  "Sleep `timeout` seconds before evaluating body"
  [timeout & body]
  `(do (Thread/sleep ~timeout) ~@body))
(time @(-> (future (wait 200 (println "'Ello, gov'na!")))
           (enqueue saying (wait 400 "Pip pip!") (println @saying))
           (enqueue saying (wait 100 "Cheerio!") (println @saying))))
```

If I comment out the `(deref ~q)` line, then only "Cheerio!" is printed. Why do I need deref here to get other side effects?

Comment: I can't quite figure out what this code is supposed to achieve. But this is probably not intended: first `enqueue` receives the `future` as its first argument, second `enqueue`  receives the `promise` created within the first `enqueue`. Also what is `saying`?

Comment: `saying` is just a name for the promise. you can use any other name, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you comment out `(deref ~q)`, the code passed with `q` is never evaluated, so the nested futures don't come into existence.

Macroexpansion:

```
(macroexpand '(-> (future (wait 200 (println "'Ello, gov'na!")))
                  (enqueue saying (wait 400 "Pip pip!") (println @saying))
                  (enqueue saying (wait 100 "Cheerio!") (println @saying))))
;;-> ....
(clojure.pprint/pp)

(let*
 [saying (clojure.core/promise)]
 (clojure.core/future
   (clojure.core/deliver saying (do (wait 100 "Cheerio!"))))
 ;; no code ended up here...
 (println @saying)
 saying)
```

Comment: In case anyone else finds themselves stumbling over this, the `deref` isn't the essential thing here: it's that the `q` parameter is being referenced at all. `enqueue` will continue to work as expected if that `deref` is replaced with `do`, `println` or various other functions.